How to show request body using django rest framework and drf_spectacular in function based views
I have the following problem, which has been difficult for me to find documentation on function-based views to document them with drf_spectacular since all this is found for class-based views
I have tried different ways to document the requestBody in swagger using serializers_class, manual objects, inline_serializers but all this without any success, here I leave a fragment of my code and a screenshot of how it should be and where should I be
@extend_schema(
    summary="Fetch order information",
    description="This endpoint filter orders based on the provided parameters.",
    tags=["orders"],
    request=OrderInfoParamsSerializer,    # HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    responses={
        200: OrderInfoSerializer(many=True),
    },
)
@api_view(["GET"])
@token_required
def order_info(request: Request) -> Response:
    params = OrderInfoParamsSerializer(data=request.data)
    if not params.is_valid():
        return Response({"error": params.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    params = params.validated_data
   
    ...

class OrderInfoParamsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    order_id = serializers.IntegerField(
        required=False, allow_null=True, help_text="Filter by order ID"
    )

class OrderInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = "__all__"

I tried to migrate the views to those based on classes where it only worked with one in the POST method not with the GET (I could migrate all my views if this worked)
I didn't want to have to refactor the entire project and would like to be able to find some solution that works for function-based views.

Why is that an issue? You are overridden the already set request schema to None.

Because I can't document the requestBody in the GET methods of my API in Swagger

Apparently, since the GET method does not have a request body according to the HTTP standard, drf-spectacular does not recognize it.

Only unsafe methods can have a requestBody

https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/issues/809

The request body applicable for this operation. The requestBody is fully supported in HTTP methods where the HTTP 1.1 specification RFC7231 has explicitly defined semantics for request bodies. In other cases where the HTTP spec is vague (such as GET, HEAD and DELETE), requestBody is permitted but does not have well-defined semantics and SHOULD be avoided if possible.

https://swagger.io/specification/#operation-object

Merely attaching @extend_schema just like with regular class-based views does the trick.
@extend_schema(request=OrderInfoParamsSerializer, methods=["GET"])
DRF Spectacular doesn’t do anything different with function based views. The @extend_schema decorator behaves the same way for both. Remember to add methods=[•••].

It's exactly what I did and it doesn't work in the GET method, apparently u have to force it but i don't know how ...

Add the methods=["GET"]. Check if it works now.
